# how to make static page responsive??

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am tying to make html file responsive but I have problem that when I change the width to 90%
it make webpage and make portfolio seaction go to far right and content section to far left with gab between section. what aima trying to do is make web page fixable?
I add link to fiddle js for may static page 
http://jsfiddle.net/aElnajjar/YJA9E/

My CSS after I add persent

```
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */

-
+* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
 /*reset css*/
 article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { 
        display:block; 
@@ -17,6 +17,8 @@ article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #5F5E59;
        background: url(images/bg_body.jpg) left top repeat;
+       width: 100%;
+

    }
    a:link, a:active, a:visited {
@@ -35,28 +37,26 @@ article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    #block-twitter {
-       width: 700px;
-       height: 60px;
-       position: relative;
+       width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px 200px 0 0;
+       float: right;
+       
    }
    #block-title {
-       width: 900px;
-       height: 80px;
-       position: relative;
-       margin: 0 auto;
+       width: 90%;
+       position: right;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    #main-content {
-       width: 900px;
-       position: relative;
+       width: 90%;
+       position: right;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    footer {
-       width: 900px;
-       position: relative;
-       margin: 0  auto;
+       width: 90%;
+
+   
        clear: both;
        padding: 30px 0;
        background: url(images/img_star.png) left top repeat-x;
@@ -73,6 +73,8 @@ article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:14px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #0000;
+   width: 90%;
+
 }

 #block-twitter span.tweet-time {
@@ -301,6 +303,4 @@ section#portfolio {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #999;
        clear: both;

-   }
-
-   /* -------- */
+   }
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want it to be dynamic with animations and popups and things like that, or do you want it to be dynamically-sized?

Comment: I am try to implement responsive design I need to change it from static to fluid template type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of your divs have fixed widths (eg #block-title 900px, #main-content 900px ) so this will  block any responsive behaviour.

You could try using percentages instead of fixed width values. In practice you may have to combine this approach with the use of [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) to further customise the layout based on the visitor's viewport

Another option if you haven't already considered it, is using one of the many good responsive frameworks, for example [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com). Once you get up to speed with them they will save you a huge amount of time and give good, cross-browser results.

Good luck!

Comment: are their  away to change it percentages?

Comment: Please don't use **is.gd** links or other tricks to get around the jsfiddle rules. I've removed the link entirely because **is.gd** links hide where the user is being taken.